# Drools: Default value for queries in case of no match

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-kie-server

I'm writing a Drools rule set processing events of type `A` and `B`; and in many of the rules I need to compare `A`'s attribute `timestamp` to maximum of a subset of `B`'s attribute `windowStart` to qualify that `A` event. If that subset of `B` is an empty set, I assume there is no windowStart, and so the value `0` is desired. Any `A`'s with the a `timestamp` greater than `windowStart` will qualify.

Consider the following pseudo code for elaboration:

```
long findMaxWindowStartOrZero(int bID)
{
    Set bSubset = getAllBWithID(bID);
    if(bSubset is empty) return 0;
    return max(bSubset, B::windowStart);
}
```

without such query, LHS of every rule concerning this comparison needs to be duplicated, once to account for absence of any `B` and once to find the actual maximum when the subset is non-empty.

Having such query as the pseudo code above makes this task substantially easier, and removes the need to branch the LHS. Is it possible to do that? Is there any drawback or benefit for doing that instead of branching LHS of mentioned rules?

Answer (score 0):

```
rule qualify_A
when
    accumulate( B( id == "bID", $ws: windowStart ); $mws: max( $ws ) )
    $a: A( timestamp > $mws )
then
    ...process $a...
end
```

I think that this rule does not fire if there are no matching Bs. To work around this, insert a B with windowStart set to 0. This dummy could also be used to define the value for matching B's `id`:

```
rule qualify_A
when
    B( $id: id, windowStart == 0 )   // the dummy, defines id 
    accumulate( B( id == $id, $ws: windowStart ); $mws: max( $ws ) )
    $a: A( timestamp > $mws )
then
    ...process $a...
end
```